# Does Google Maps block requests coming from an ip for any reason?

Tags: java, google-maps

I use Java to get a map using the Google Maps static API. I created an itext image as:

```
Image image = Image.getInstance(new URL(urlString));
```

This code was working fine until two days. About two days back I was told that my IP address is blocked because of spam emails. Yesterday I found that the above code is not working. I would like to know, whether this is because of IP address blocking.

Does Google Maps block IP addresses because of spam emails?

Comment: Any pubic api will black list ip's that it perceives as acting maliciously. It's called a fire wall.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are scraping static maps images. Please be advised that this is not allowed by Terms of Services, paragraph 10.5 (c), (d)
You cannot download and save images.

> **No use of Content outside the Service**. You will not use any Content outside of the Service except as expressly permitted to do so in Subsection (d). For example, you will not export or save the Content to a third party’s platform or service.
>
> **No caching or storage**. You will not pre-fetch, cache, index, or store any Content to be used outside the Service.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions

> You may not store and serve copies of images generated using the Google Static Maps API from your website. All web pages that require static images must link the src attribute of an HTML img tag or the CSS background-image attribute of an HTML div tag directly to the Google Static Maps API so that all map images are displayed within the HTML content of the web page and served directly to end users by Google.

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_staticmaps_reuse

Indeed, if Google detects suspicious behavior they can block an IP address.